# Ligatures in unicode?

Tags: unicode, ligatures

I am aware that ligatures are not characters, and that they shouldn't be included as such.
I'm just wondering, however, whether some might have made their way into unicode regardless.

There's `ß`, which is a bit of an edge-case, since it's historically a ligature, but nowadays used as though it were its own character. Is it the only such example?

Comment: Perhaps Æ/æ and Œ/œ. You can find them used in old books in English. These were originally ligatures, which kind of became letters, then kind of went out of fashion.  In Old English, æ was called "æsc" (pronounced like "ash").

Comment: @BillyKerr were they really ligatures, though? i.e. were a and e always contracted when adjacent to each other, or was this a special case of a and e being next to each other representing a different sound or semantic element?

Comment: You can type œ and æ directly from a Mac keyboard [ISO English] with no modification, they exist as unicode chars. There are many others, harder to get to - Ĳ ĳ ƕ ǅ ʤ ʦ ʧ ʨ ʩ ʪ ʫ ʬ …etc, etc. Whether you would consider these ligatures… maybe not. They're probably all classed as digraphs.

Comment: Well, wikipedia says so, although I wouldn't trust wikipedia as a source. They are still sometimes used in spellings in the UK today, but often no longer joined as ligatures, such as in Encyclopaedia. Americans spell it Encylopedia.